# CSS - Manipulating circles

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm developing an angularjs app around the boardgame Mastermind. To show the 4 colour pegs and 4 check pegs I'm using labels and setting the border radius to 50%. My div:

```
<div>
    <div id="pegs">
        <div ng-repeat="colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index">
            <span class="colourCircle" style="background-color:{{colour}}"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="checkPegs">
            <span class="checkCircle" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=1?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=1?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
            <span class="checkCircle" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=2?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=2?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
            <br />
            <span class="checkCircle" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=3?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=3?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
            <span class="checkCircle" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=4?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=4?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The outputted HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="pegs">
        <!-- ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index --><div ng-repeat="colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index" class="ng-scope">
            <span class="colourCircle" style="background-color:yellow"></span>
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index --><div ng-repeat="colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index" class="ng-scope">
            <span class="colourCircle" style="background-color:yellow"></span>
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index --><div ng-repeat="colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index" class="ng-scope">
            <span class="colourCircle" style="background-color:red"></span>
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index --><div ng-repeat="colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index" class="ng-scope">
            <span class="colourCircle" style="background-color:red"></span>
        </div><!-- end ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index -->
        <div id="checkPegs">
            <span class="checkCircle noPeg" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=1?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=1?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
            <span class="checkCircle noPeg" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=2?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=2?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
            <br>
            <span class="checkCircle noPeg" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=3?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=3?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
            <span class="checkCircle noPeg" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=4?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=4?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.colourCircle{
    border-radius:50%;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    float:left;
    margin:2px;
}
.checkCircle{
    float:left;
    height:15px;
    width:15px;
    margin:2px;
}
.orangePeg{
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: orange;
}
.whitePeg{
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: white;
}
.noPeg{
    border-radius:50%;
    border-color:black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
}
#pegs{
    height:60px;
    margin:5px;
}
```

It currently looks like this:

[image: circles]

I'm trying to make the 4 smaller circles on the right bigger and centered vertically. What's the best way to do this?
I'm also looking for a way to center the entire div to the middle.

Also, the width and height of the circles is now hardcoded. Is there a way to set this dynamically so it scales better?

Comment: Can you post the outputted html?

Comment: I updated it with the output of what I get in brackets. Hope that helps

Comment: So this is still very confusing on what you are trying to do?  Are you trying to put the colored circles inside of the the outlined circles?  So, peg vs no peg?  Can you post a screenshot of the design?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to have a look. I added a picture that should hopefully illustrate it better. I'm trying to make the pegs on the right side (they can be orange, white or empty) bigger, and also center them vertically. If I just increase the width and height they don't line up any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the display property on your peg container to tabel and display all child divs to display table-cell with a vertical-align of middle. To center all circles in the horizontal just add a margin "0 auto" to the pegs div. Take look at the snippet and you will get the idea.

```css
.colourCircle{
    border-radius:50%;
    height:60px;
    width:60px;
    float:left;
    margin:2px;
}
.checkCircle{
    float:left;
    height:18px;
    width:18px;
    margin:2px;
}
.orangePeg{
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: orange;
}
.whitePeg{
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color: white;
}
.noPeg{
    border-radius:50%;
    border-color:black;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
}
#pegs {
    height:60px;
    margin:5px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#pegs > div {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="pegs">
    <!-- ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index --><div ng-repeat="colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index" class="ng-scope">
    <span class="colourCircle" style="background-color:yellow"></span>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index --><div ng-repeat="colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index" class="ng-scope">
    <span class="colourCircle" style="background-color:yellow"></span>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index --><div ng-repeat="colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index" class="ng-scope">
    <span class="colourCircle" style="background-color:red"></span>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index --><div ng-repeat="colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index" class="ng-scope">
    <span class="colourCircle" style="background-color:red"></span>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: colour in guess.getCombination() track by $index -->
    <div id="checkPegs">
      <span class="checkCircle noPeg" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=1?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=1?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
      <span class="checkCircle noPeg" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=2?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=2?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
      <br>
      <span class="checkCircle noPeg" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=3?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=3?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
      <span class="checkCircle noPeg" ng-class="guess.getOrange()>=4?'orangePeg':guess.getOrange()+guess.getWhite()>=4?'whitePeg':'noPeg'"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great. Is there a way to center the entire "pegs" div in the middle of the window? I think the 'float:left' property might be preventing it, but if I change it the span doesn't show up.

Comment: To center your pegs div horizontal just add a margin of zero to top and bottom and auto to left and right, i did edit the snippet, take a look at it.
But you might want to edit your question also, to not confuse other readers.

Answer (score 1):

To center the circles I think that `display: flex` is the better choice in this case. The code is simple:

```
#pegs{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height:100%;
}
```

Also, I think that tables is not the best option for this kind of issue, because tables is to show tabular data, not to layout. But nevertheless, you are free to choose. You can check the result with this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/s5nfLwva/1/

Comment: Should this center the entire "pegs" div in the middle of the window or is this just for individual circles? I think the 'float:left' property might be preventing it, but if I change it the span doesn't show up.

Comment: I edit my answer, centering pegs. If you want to see more clear the vertical centering, change the height of body. And please, don't use tables for this, just a recommendation.